# NestJS Upload multiple files with dto

Tags: express, file-upload, nestjs

I'm trying to upload files with dto object, but got error:

**[Nest] 8296   - 11/29/2021, 1:05:08 AM   [ExceptionsHandler] request entity too large +378162ms
PayloadTooLargeError: request entity too large**

Here is my code:

```
@Post()
  @UseInterceptors(
    FileFieldsInterceptor([
      { name: 'picture', maxCount: 1 },
      { name: 'audio', maxCount: 1 },
    ]),
  )
  create(@UploadedFiles() files, @Body() dto: CreateTrackDto) {
    console.log('files', files);
    return this.trackService.create(dto, '', '');
  }
```

I've tried to upload files without dto object and it works fine, but when I added the second param as dto object from the body I got this.
Actually tried set limits for uploaded files in main.ts file like this:

```
// app.use(json({ limit: '50mb' }));
// app.use(urlencoded({ extended: true, limit: '50mb' }));
```

and set limits in FileFieldsInterceptor in localOptions object

but got the same error.

Does anyone know how to fix it?

```
"@nestjs/common": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/core": "^7.6.15",
"@nestjs/mongoose": "^9.0.1",
"@nestjs/platform-express": "^7.6.15"

"@types/multer": "^1.4.7"

windows 10
```